# SQL Aggregate Function Grouping with WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table that has data like the following:

| shift | event |
| --- | --- |
| shift 1 | 0 |
| shift 1 | 1 |
| shift 2 | 0 |

What I need to do is get a returned aggregate grouped by shift that displays both the total number of occurrences of the shift, and the number of events that occurred for the shift. Something like this:

```
shift 1 - 2 - 1
shift 2 - 1 - 0
```

The query I have tried most recently is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    shift,
    COUNT(shift) AS totalShifts,
    (SELECT COUNT(shift) FROM table WHERE event = 1) AS totalEvents
FROM table
GROUP BY shift
```

This query successfully returns the total number of shifts for each unique shift but keeps returning total events = 1 not independent of shift for each shift:

```
shift 1 - 2 - 1
shift 2 - 1 - 1
```

I have tried adding additional group by's and partitioning the table data but I always get this same result. What do I need to add to get this to work as desired?

Comment: Instead of the subquery use `sum(case when event = cast(1 as bit) then 1 end)` Your subquery would work if you had correlated based on the shift number but there's no need for that here.

Comment: That worked. I believe the issue was the BIT type conversion

Comment: Yeah, you can't sum up bits. But that cast is actually more for indexing and sort of documenting the data type involved there. It should work otherwise but there would be an implied cast on `event` to turn it into an `int` first. The result of the `case` is an `int` which *is* summable.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    shift,
    COUNT(1) As totalShifts,
    SUM(CAST(event As int)) As totalEvents
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    shift
```

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=790c29c962b43f08144deec6ec78a667)

Your current query is counting all "event 1" rows for every row in the resultset, regardless of the shift.

Comment: I still got the same thing I was getting before with this. Does it make a difference if the event column is of type BIT?

Comment: @AddisonWaege I see the problem; I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate functions Count and Sum with Concat function.

```
Select Concat([shift],' - ', Count(*),' - ', Sum(Convert(int,[event])))
From [Table]
Group by [shift]
Order by [shift]
```